# How find out which part of Linux kernel code was changed in which kernel release

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am working on Linux kernel module, which has be to more or less Linux kernel version agnostic. It means I am forced to add plenty of version specific code and wrap it with ifdefs. Not the best solution...

The problem is Linux kernel source has been changed many times. For instance, in the very beginning function foo was declared as follows

```
static void foo(int a, int b)
```

And later it was changed to

```
static void foo(int a, int b, int c)
```

And finally it looks like

```
static int foo(int a, int b, int c)
```

My question is how can I find out in which Linux kernel version function foo was modified?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
git log --oneline --decorate -32 -G"foo\\(" -- [filename]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your underlying problem is that you have to keep changing your module every time the kernel's internal interface changes, then the [official answer](https://github.com/tinganho/linux-kernel/blob/master/Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt) is to put your module into the main kernel tree, so kernel devs will update your module every time they change something it depends on.

This may not be possible, if for example you do not wish to publicise the source code.

As a guess: you could move all the top-secret functionality of the module into a userland process, leaving a small-enough amount of code in the module that you don't mind being public, but I have no idea if that is possible for you. It *would* also help to turn kernel panics into mere process crashes.